# SQL Error on Storing Images with VARBINARY(max)

Tags: mysql, database, image

I am trying to create a table on a database; the table name is Pizza and can store an image found around the internet.

```
CREATE TABLE Pizza(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    image VARBINARY(max),
    price INTEGER NOT NULL,
    size VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255)
);
```

I found that for storing images it is a good idea to use `VARBINARY(max)`, but this is giving me the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'max),

price INTEGER NOT NULL,
size VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(25' at line 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support 'max' as length like Microsoft SQL Server does. If you want a column that can store maximum size binary data, use LONGBLOB.